# Are there drawbacks to giving an .html page (with no server side script) a .php extension?

Tags: php, html, web-applications, file-extension

Using .php for a file extension allows for all HTML, CSS, JS, and PHP content, etc., while .html does not allow PHP code to be read by the server-side engine.

As a rule of thumb I just use .php for my files even if I have no PHP code in them.

So... Is there ever a time when, for some reason, one ought to use .html specifically? Perhaps search engines index the file differently/better or it loads faster or something? But as of now I see no reason to do so, even with a file that has no PHP content.

Apparently no one is understanding the question:

Does it make *any* difference at all if I save a file as .html over .php when I have no PHP content? Shouldn't there be some difference? The file is clearly a different entity when saved with a different extension.

Comment: Because not everyone knows or wants to use PHP?

Comment: @Paul: no, that's not a good reason. The question is if it makes any difference

Comment: What if my server doesn't have PHP?

Comment: @njk: The question is clearly implying that the server does have it

Comment: This has less to do with the extension and more to do with how your server is configured. You can configure your server to execute .html files as php, no problem.

Comment: @khanahk I don't think any of us are search engine experts, but when a search engine crawls your website it will see plain HTML/CSS/JS regardless of whether it's a `.php` or `.html` file.

Comment: @GlennDayton unless the search engine looks at the file extension, it will see no difference. The server only spits out the final rendered output (minus whatever JS does) so it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: @khanahk Having `.php` extension for XML files can cause syntax error if XML declaration is treated as beginning of PHP code. Also, you have to explicitly send `Content-type` header for CSS, JS, ... files if you rename them to `*.php`.

Comment: @duri was that comment intended for someone else?

Comment: @Paul Oh, sorry. It was for the OP.

Comment: @GlennDayton There is no need to "expose your filesystem" like that at all. Look at stackoverflow, no extensions in the url.

Comment: @Esailija Well if someone was really out to determine your filesystem couldn't they just look at the headers. Also, I think stackoverflow did it for more of usability (making things clean) and SEO tactics.

Comment: No need to expose it in the headers either.

Comment: I still don't understand how this got so many downvotes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you give a plain HTML file a .php extension, it causes the PHP engine to parse it.  While the performance hit is negligible, it's still an unnecessary waste of resources and a best practice would be to avoid it by giving your non php pages an extension of html.

Comment: THIS is what was needed. Goodness gracious. Simple as it is.

Comment: @khanahk how is this different from my answer?

Comment: it is different in that it is more and in that it considers the individual asking the question. This answer TEACHES something; yours STATED something. I've been banned from asking questions now because no one saw the simplicity in my question and preferred ignorance over understanding

Comment: It actually answers the question...   Khanahk wasn't asking the difference between PHP and HTML, they were asking if there was any drawback to giving html pages a .php extension.   Plus this answer is less patronizing

Comment: I really don't know why you (khanahk) got burned so bad for your question. It may be obvious to some and you could have worded it more concisely, but it's still a valid question that doesn't deserve the response it received.

Comment: @LondonDrugs_MediaServices: granted it could've been worded better, and I appreciate the answer, understanding, and edits to the question

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully this satisfies this tough question.

PHP = server side language, meaning additional resources are used by the server.

HTML = client side language, which is just displayed by browser.

Comment: No, you don't understand the question and take me for a neophite

Comment: @khanahk I don't think that anyone will be able to answer your question.

Comment: @khanahk let's say you want to drive from City A to City B. You have two cars that will take you from A to B in the same time. Car A (PHP) has a V-8 engine and Car B (HTML) has a V-4 engine. Why would you want to drive Car A and pay the extra gas?

Comment: Okay, that's something. So using a .php file extension puts more of a 'task' on the server and thus is fundamentally slower than a .html file?

Comment: @khanahk Like I explained in my answer, the server needs to use PHP to render your HTML file.

Comment: You are correct -- the example you gave is what helped me to understand it, and this at least is appreciated